# Flagging a question as duplicate with more then one answer

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I recently encountered the issue of multiple questions hanging around that answers the new question being asked.

There was a question about placing 2 `div`s side by side.  The OP had a bug in his code and couldn't get it to work.  I KNOW for a fact that this has been answered multiple times.  My first inclination was to flag this one as duplicate.  Searching for the "exact" duplicate led to seeing all these questions with small "twists" to it.  The technique was all the same, answer slightly different because of the customized "twist" to it.  Same as this question with his specific bug.

I ended up flagging this questions with the "closest" question.  Bugs were different, but answer should have been the same, technique is the same.  I could have picked multiple questions that were "duplicates".

Could it be possible to flag a question and provide multiple links of different questions as duplicate?  Basically stating that if the user took the time to look around a bit, the answer is already out there.

This got me thinking as... should we be debugging code or should we be providing answers to problems.  In this senario, the problem is placing 2 `div`s side by side, which was answered.  Would be a duplicate.  If we want to debug, then, no, this bug/malformed code was not yet presented in this particular manner.

I'll conclude with the idea that it "could" be cool to identify multiple questions of the same general concept, such as this one, that could be merged into a community wiki and remove all the "bug" fixes.

Comment: related: [Allow unlimited possible duplicate of actions without actually voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164643) (duplicate?) [Allow same user to add multiple links as possible dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1385), [When is a duplicate question not a dupe?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12182), [What is an exact duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38375), [Close reason proposal: "answer exists elsewhere"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95805) [Why do people use similar answers as justification for closing questions as dupe?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85725)